# How to order legend levels on animation plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I want to make an animation plot with plotly in R, when I make a normal plot without *frame* option I have the levels of the legend ordered as I desired but when I add the *frame* option the levels of the legend are disordered. I don't know how to fix this problem.

Here is the code and the results I have:

- I need legend levels have an specific order:

```
data_plot$var_group = factor(data_plot$var_group, c("R_D","R_C-","R_C+","R_B-","R_B+","R_A-","R_A+"))

> levels(data_plot$var_group)
[1] "R_D"  "R_C-" "R_C+" "R_B-" "R_B+" "R_A-" "R_A+"
```

- When I run this:

```
  base <- plot_ly(x = data_plot[,"var_X"], 
            y = data_plot[,"var_Y"], 
            size = data_plot[,"var_population"] ,
            color = data_plot[,"var_group"], 
            hoverinfo = "text",
            type='scatter',
            mode='markers',
            showlegend = T)
```

- I get this result:
  [image]
- This is okey, but when I add the frame option:

```
base <- plot_ly(x = data_plot[,"var_X"], 
            y = data_plot[,"var_Y"], 
            size = data_plot[,"var_population"] ,
            color = data_plot[,"var_group"], 
            hoverinfo = "text",
            frame = data_plot[,'var_year'],
            type='scatter',
            mode='markers',
            showlegend = T)
```

- I have this result, with diferent order levels in the legend:
  [image]
- Here is the data:

```
> data_plot
   var_group var_year var_population     var_X    var_Y
1       R_A+     2010         441586  7.971633 46.61086
2       R_A+     2011         441586 19.797109 40.76217
3       R_A+     2012         441586 19.766277 46.02090
4       R_A+     2013         441586 16.504366 51.60697
5       R_A+     2014         441586  6.629429 42.00877
6       R_A+     2015         441586 10.207176 50.59914
7       R_A+     2016         441586  8.113253 50.51997
8       R_A+     2017         441586 13.809222 45.65124
9       R_A+     2018         441586 21.204559 54.54564
10      R_A+     2019         441586 16.323557 50.61546
11      R_A+     2020         441586  9.395053 46.67655
12      R_A-     2010         752842 13.748339 47.09175
13      R_A-     2011         752842 15.945362 45.58824
14      R_A-     2012         752842 14.878077 48.51219
15      R_A-     2013         752842 13.462869 50.68530
16      R_A-     2014         752842 13.736505 49.01226
17      R_A-     2015         752842 13.782079 45.78995
18      R_A-     2016         752842 13.089312 47.15687
19      R_A-     2017         752842 14.296593 45.50281
20      R_A-     2018         752842 16.116978 46.94360
21      R_A-     2019         752842 15.477477 46.29914
22      R_A-     2020         752842 13.771521 46.58368
23      R_B+     2010         779656 13.932735 48.31006
24      R_B+     2011         779656 14.388946 51.73630
25      R_B+     2012         779656 15.367567 47.42770
26      R_B+     2013         779656 15.349203 43.48819
27      R_B+     2014         779656 14.545901 49.89104
28      R_B+     2015         779656 14.073454 48.59113
29      R_B+     2016         779656 14.669861 46.76586
30      R_B+     2017         779656 14.235979 48.20083
31      R_B+     2018         779656 15.690158 48.89362
32      R_B+     2019         779656 14.141815 47.11869
33      R_B+     2020         779656 14.196556 45.63945
34      R_B-     2010        1241331 13.850250 47.31124
35      R_B-     2011        1241331 15.615122 48.40796
36      R_B-     2012        1241331 15.821155 47.71673
37      R_B-     2013        1241331 14.745171 48.99816
38      R_B-     2014        1241331 14.179987 49.49550
39      R_B-     2015        1241331 13.511352 44.73631
40      R_B-     2016        1241331 13.518238 48.37322
41      R_B-     2017        1241331 14.509204 48.63535
42      R_B-     2018        1241331 15.114272 50.32725
43      R_B-     2019        1241331 15.210563 46.65757
44      R_B-     2020        1241331 13.324742 46.36694
45      R_C+     2010        1944078 14.224204 47.98332
46      R_C+     2011        1944078 14.264518 48.04793
47      R_C+     2012        1944078 14.941984 46.64478
48      R_C+     2013        1944078 14.466030 47.96907
49      R_C+     2014        1944078 14.725540 47.61507
50      R_C+     2015        1944078 14.168740 47.53845
51      R_C+     2016        1944078 14.174140 46.54725
52      R_C+     2017        1944078 14.982952 47.07512
53      R_C+     2018        1944078 14.531390 47.99920
54      R_C+     2019        1944078 14.935974 46.80847
55      R_C+     2020        1944078 13.561471 46.98083
56      R_C-     2010        1502848 14.980631 47.66160
57      R_C-     2011        1502848 14.655282 46.63385
58      R_C-     2012        1502848 13.883987 48.41544
59      R_C-     2013        1502848 14.474711 46.26512
60      R_C-     2014        1502848 15.225393 48.90736
61      R_C-     2015        1502848 14.834675 48.89604
62      R_C-     2016        1502848 14.319218 47.17255
63      R_C-     2017        1502848 15.215459 47.63817
64      R_C-     2018        1502848 14.090972 46.29257
65      R_C-     2019        1502848 15.105556 45.71682
66      R_C-     2020        1502848 14.497683 50.18621
67       R_D     2010         893489 14.540623 47.03672
68       R_D     2011         893489 14.636348 46.55389
69       R_D     2012         893489 14.931650 46.60181
70       R_D     2013         893489 13.671536 46.17947
71       R_D     2014         893489 14.756695 48.01608
72       R_D     2015         893489 14.665928 47.21726
73       R_D     2016         893489 15.407930 48.55170
74       R_D     2017         893489 14.602070 50.54327
75       R_D     2018         893489 14.551677 48.19881
76       R_D     2019         893489 14.713524 47.78081
77       R_D     2020         893489 14.583820 47.31329
```

Comment: Don't suppose you ever fixed this? I have the exact same problem now and am at a loss.

Comment: I have the same problem too.